Movie about an evil witch trapped in a mirror
I saw this movie once back when I was in elementary school (likely between 1994-1998). The movie was likely made between the 80's and early 90's. I saw the movie some time around the holiday season, though I'm unsure if the movie was considered a holiday movie or simply took place during the winter. The movie was live action.
Here is what I remember from the movie: The movie starts out with the telling of a legend about an evil witch who becomes trapped in a mirror. The mirror is shattered, but shards from the mirror still possess bit's of the evil witch's power. The main character of the movie is a little girl and her brother. The two of them are outside playing in the snow as it's snowing. As the boy is looking up at the falling snow a shard of the mirror falls from the sky into his eye. He suddenly starts acting weird and the little girl becomes worried. She runs up to him and puts her hands on his face trying to get him to snap out of it. It's then that she notices something in his eye. The boy disappears or is captured and brought to a fantasy realm. And the rest of the movie is the girl going after him and trying to rescue him.
I don't remember much else, but hopefully someone know's what movie this is.
What it's not: 
This movie is not "The Brother's Grimm (2004)"; although this has an evil witch/queen who appears in a mirror, and captures kids. This movie doesn't fit into the time frame and doesn't have the same plot.
This movie is not "The Lion, The Witch and the Wardrobe (1988 and 2009)"; although this has a evil witch, takes place in the winter, and has a brother who ends up serving the witch. This again doesn't contain the plot for the movie in question.
This movie is not "The Silver Chair (1990)"; while this is another Narnia movie that has some similar points (saving a male character being controlled by an evil witch), this again isn't the movie I'm looking for.

This is the plot of Hans Christian Andersen's The Snow Queen, but there were many adaptations. Try looking for the right one here and here.

@Walt yeah, that's the story I'm looking for. I'm unsure of which version I saw, as there appears to be 4 different versions of the movie between 1985 and 1992. But up until now I never knew what the story was called, now that I know I can at-least narrow down which version I saw as a kid.

Was just gonna say, "is it The Silver Chair"? lol

How about one of these? http://www.imdb.com/find?s=all&q=snow%20queen

You're thinking of the Faerie Tale Theater version of the Hans Christian Andersen story "The Snow Queen." 
You can watch it on YouTube, here's part 1:




Video does not work unless you go straight to YouTube; could you add an inline video that works?
